# Check for a string in an array of URLs

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of links and another array of product SKUs.
i.e. 
$array1 = ( sku1, sku2, sku3...... );
$array2 = ( "/product/U072369/Casual-T-Shirt", "/product/U072369/Training-Bag","/product/U072369/Shirt" .....)

The links in the array have SKU as a part of url

I want to check if the SKUs in array1 matches the sku in the any of the links in array2 and if it matches then do something with that link.

Need some guidance on how to achieve this in php.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to find the sku in the url string:

```
$array1 = array( 'sku1', 'Training-Bag', 'sku3'); 
$array2 = array( "/product/U072369/Casual-T-Shirt", "/product/U072369/Training-Bag","/product/U072369/Shirt");

function search($array2,$array1){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array2 as $url){

        foreach($$array1 as $sku){
            $sku = '/'.$sku;
            if(strpos($url,$sku) !== false){
                $result[] = array('url'=>$url,'sku'=>$sku);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
var_dump(search($array2,$array1));
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying array_search & in_array, with breaking the url string again into an array of words. But this perfect.